# Show product price in some categories for guest users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, price

I want to show to guest users price to products but only in some categories..this code disable product price and add to cart button for all products..to mention i have problem with hidding add to cart button, its not working (i use woodmart theme)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_and_button', 9999, 2 );
 
function hide_price_and_button( $price, $product ) {
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
      $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Login to see prices', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 1000 );
   }
   return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter and set `woocommerce_is_purchasable` to false.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
```

So you could end up with something like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price', 9999, 2 );

function hide_price( $price, $product ) {
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
      $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Login to see prices', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';
   }
   return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'hide_button', 10, 2);

function hide_button( $is_purchasable, $object ) {
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
      $is_purchasable = false;
   }
   return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Comment: Button "Read more" now shows up..like there is no stock so you can read more...

Comment: Yes, it's default behavior of not purchasable product in Woocommerce... You can hide it with CSS or change the text `.outofstock .button.product_type_simple::before {content: "Out of Stock"; /* New custom text. */}`